# Why does program now require UAC confirmation where it didn't before?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have a program which has not changed. It previously did not require User Account Control confirmation to launch, but now it does. My User Account Control Settings has not changed either; it is still **Default - Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer**.

What might have caused this change?

Comment: Unless it presents a problem to you, listing the actual program would help. If the program is not well known describing the actions of the program, or intended purpose of the program could be useful. Also where/how you aquired the program could be important.

Comment: It’s possible this is the work of the program compatibility assistant. The settings for this are somewhere in the registry.

Comment: It's not a common program: [pVault](http://www.paperlessenvironments.com/PRODUCTS/pvault.aspx). It's a client application for a server-based document database. (Actually it has two executables, one which is just the client application and another that is a self-updating version that first checks for updates then launches the client. Previously only the updater required UAC confirmation. Now both executables require it.)

Comment: Open a command prompt and run the following command: `find /i "level=" "X:\Path\to\program.exe"` Repeat the same for the updater executable, then post here the output you got in both cases.

Comment: For the updater, the `find` result is: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>`. For the client application, `find` returns nothing.